# Provide review capabilities in the Stack Exchange native mobile application

Tags: feature-request, review, android-app, mobile-web

#### We ought to be bringing down that Close Vote review count down, and performing all other review duties through the mobile application.

I am **extremely** happy with the mobile application with the single issue that, on my phone, I cannot be doing my duty to review First Posts, Late Answers, Low Quality Posts, Suggested Edits, and soon Reopen Votes and Close Votes ( once I reach 3k reputation in 5+ days [ heh ] ).

#### What prevents this? Performing review operations from the mobile application is critical.

I know it is a slightly involved activity, but most of us have pretty hefty gadgets with multiple tabs possible, and plenty of ability to perform fully, no matter where we are. We can all be spending plenty of our down time decompressing, by performing our duties... even without getting in trouble for being at our desks and in our labs too long. I say we keep peace in our homes, and bring in this feature set.

---

*I waded through the possible duplicates to this question and have not found any. Do flag if I am wrong.* I use the Android version. I am guessing the iOS version also needs this functionality but am not sure.

Comment: Are you talking about the Android app or the mobile version of the site?

Comment: Question updated! Thanks @Mat for the clarification request.

Comment: @Mat, ah yes, there is a duplicate apparently. I will leave this up unless closed since that version of the question seems very meager. I did just vote for it though.

Comment: Duplicates are still valuable as signposts.  This one is more detailed and people in the future may find the other via this one.  So don't delete it even though it'll likely get closed; it's still valuable.